# Get time of last git commit quickly

Tags: git, performance

I have an issue of getting time of last commit quickly.
I am on version 2.32.0.windows.2 so I should have all the core graph functionality, I even manually enabled it with:

```
git config --global core.commitGraph true
git config --global gc.writeCommitGraph true
git commit-graph write
```

Still for me the show and log ways of getting last commit time are very slow.

> time git show -s --format=%ci
>
> 2021-12-01 18:55:17 +0100
>
> real    0m1.410s
>
> user    0m0.015s
>
> sys     0m0.015s

> time git log -1 --date=short --pretty=format:%ci
>
> 2021-12-01 18:55:17> +0100
>
> real    0m1.349s
>
> user    0m0.000s
>
> sys     0m0.031s

P.S. I know 1.4 seconds does not seem like a lot, but for me it is, for some other reasons this is executed many times in my project.

EDIT: this is git trace:

> git log -1 --date=short --pretty=format:%ci
>
> 18:57:13.743566 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable
> dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
>
> 18:57:13.749988 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git log -1
> --date=short '--pretty=format:%ci'
>
> 18:57:13.766512 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: unset
> GIT_PAGER_IN_USE; LESS=FRX LV=-c 'diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=4 -RFX'
>
> 18:57:14.816139 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable
> dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
>
> 18:57:14.820048 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git config
> --list
>
> 2021-12-03 09:50:40 +0100
>
> 18:57:15.177615 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable
> dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
>
> 18:57:15.182528 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git config
> --bool core.sparseCheckout

Comment: Given that the user and system times are zero (!) and about 31 ms respectively, I'd say the entire 1.4 seconds of real time is something you're stuck with that has nothing to do with Git. You might try collecting the commit hash IDs that you're interested in and using `git log --no-walk --stdin` with your formatting options: feed the hash IDs to `git log` on standard input and correlate the output to the input (consider adding `%H` to the formatting directive). Then you can use a single `git log` invocation and amortize the 1.4 second overhead over all the commits.

Comment: you can try setting debug environment variables, to see if you can spot the part that makes it so slow : `GIT_TRACE=1`, `GIT_TRACE2=1` or `GIT_TRACE2_PERF=1`. You can find the list of relevant environment variables in [`git help git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_other)

Comment: Is `git cat-file -p HEAD` as slow as `git log -1` or `git show` ?

Comment: @LeGEC it is 0.1 seconds, but time is in raw integer and offset format.

Comment: @LeGEC still a good answer if you want to post it, I would upvote for sure

Comment: @LeGEC updated the question with git trace log

Comment: Well, there it is, you're not just running `git log`/`git show`, you're running `diff-so-fancy` and `less` and probably a full shell startup, which could be doing anything, especially on Windows. Try `git --no-pager show -s --pretty=%ci`.

Comment: @jthill Thank you, it works... I dont even remember installign git so fancy, I thought it is maybe installed with git. :)